# Inno Setup: How to use WizardForm.TasksList.Items in InitializeWizard?

Tags: inno-setup

I am having issues figuring out why I cannot manipulate the task checkboxes during `InitializeWizard`, but I can with `CurPageChanged`:

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"
Name: "Option1"; Description: "Option1"

[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var Index: Integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin           
  Index := WizardForm.TasksList.Items.IndexOf('Option1');
  if Index <> -1 then    
    MsgBox('Touch device checkbox found.', mbInformation, MB_OK); { THIS WORKS!! }

  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := WizardForm.TasksList.Items.IndexOf('Option1');
  if Index <> -1 then    
    MsgBox('Touch device checkbox found.', mbInformation, MB_OK); { THIS DOES NOT WORK }
end;
```

Can I not use `WizardForm.TasksList.Items` in `InitializeWizard`?  I want to be able to call `WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[Index] := False;` or possibly disable it but I'd rather do it on initialization instead of having to avoid calling code, if the user hits the back button and returns to the `wpSelectTasks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because task list is populated based on selected components.

Hence, the task list is not known in [`InitializeWizard`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard) yet. The task list is (re)generated, based on select components, whenever the `wpSelectTasks` page is entered.

So, as you have found out, the earliest moment, you can work with `TasksList` is [`CurPageChanged(wpSelectTasks)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged).

---

When unchecking the task, make sure you do not uncheck it, when user is going back to the tasks page. Actually, you should probably uncheck it on the first visit of the page only.